# Spinlock.exit with or without memory barrier

Tags: c#, .net, memory-barriers

Since memory barriers are a new concept to me Im trying to get my head around them so I wrote the following test program (C#):

```
private static void Func1()
{
    SpinLock sl = new SpinLock();

    Action action = () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            sl.Enter(ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
                sl.Exit(true);
        }
    };

    Parallel.Invoke(action, action);
}

private static void Main(string[] arg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        Func1();
}
```

The question is about the Spinlock.Exit(true) function. true means a memory barrier is issued to publish the exit action to other threads immediately.

When passing false no memory barrier is issued and then the code runs almost twice as fast.

Is it  still a correct program if the action objects would contain shared memory between threads and false is passed?
Why is the memory barrier so much slower?

Answer (score 3):

The code is correct with either Exit(true) or Exit(false), even on IA64.  The boolean argument [concerns fairness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289503.aspx).  It just happens that the implementation uses a memory barrier instruction to get that fairness.

Be careful of drawing conclusions from trivial benchmarks for this sort of thing.  Typically, the trivial benchmark will make the unfair solution look like a hands-down winner.  But in the context of a larger system, lack of fairness can sometimes do significant damage by starving one of the threads trying to make progress.  But sometimes being unfair is better.  It depends on the context.

Comment: its not really a benchmark, I just want to figure out why its twice as slow. Is it merely because an extra instruction is emitted or when are the cores all on halt until the barrier instruction is executed?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you running on?

Comment: The memory barrier does not stop any other cores, but impacts the core on which it executes in several ways.  It causes all prior instructions to complete execution and store their results into the L1 cache before any subsequent instructions start.  Without the memory barrier, the instructions can execute concurrently or out of order,  and even bypass stores to L1.  Section 2.3.3 of http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html gives more details on the pipeline for your system.

Comment: For a detailed discussion of spinlocks and fairness on Intel processors, see http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/xeon-lock-scaling-analysis-paper.pdf .